# Testing data from two different data sources

Tags: sql

I have to test data migrating from one database into google cloud platform. I need to be able to basic tests such as Intersects/Minus operations etc to make sure I’m not losing or gaining any extra data during the process. However, the tables in some instances have millions of records and so I cannot simply join the two data sources using an Sql query, not can I import the data to excel and do the comparisons. 
Can someone please advise me the best way to go about testing this? 
Note I am a software tester and so have limited technical understanding

Comment: Which Google database service are you using? Can you do CSV export from there and then import that into a local relational store for testing?

Comment: SQL knows set operations such as `INTERSECT`, `EXCEPT` (set minus, aka `MINUS` in some DBMS) and `UNION`...

Comment: A common way to test this is by checking a (small) sample manually and running some aggregate checks - e.g. that the number of records match, as well as the totals, min/max/.., the number of different values/nulls. Make sure you test incremental loads as well.

Comment: If you export to CSV, Excel, etc before testing, you're not testing the data in the database, but the data you've exported. So if the export process loses some data (e.g. rounding, truncating, or misformatting) you might miss something. As a made-up example, a decimal value of `0.3` could be stored in the database incorrectly as a floating point `0.30000000000000004`, but displayed as `0.3` in the export.

Comment: Thanks for the comments all. So, what is the most practical way to test this then? It is data warehouse testing. Like I said, it's table structures/data types should remain the same in the export, but I can't simply do a select query and join the data from source to target to compare as there is nothing I can join on. The CSV route seems to be a no go too...